# Layout with 4 divs - 2 fixed, 1 dynamic (not scrollable) and 1 fill height with scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the following behavior with HTML and CSS on a single webpage
[image: Webpage]

I got the first three areas to work (black, red, blue) but I had problems with the scrollable content (green). It works with static height, but I don't know how to fill the rest of the page dynamically.

Here is what I got

[Link to Code](http://jsfiddle.net/H27r6/)

```
<div class="body">   
<div class="menu">
    menu
</div>           
<div>
    <div class="dynamiccontent">
        <div class="errorheader">
            Errors
        </div>
        <div class="errorcontent">
            errors   
        </div>
        <div class="fixedtext">
            some text
        </div>            
        <div class="fillcontent">
            fillcontent
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.body 
{ 
    background:red; 
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
}

.menu 
{ 
    background:black;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
} 

.dynamiccontent
{
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    margin:0px auto;
    width:100%;     
    background: red;
}

.errorheader
{ 
    color: white;    
    text-align: center;    
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

.errorcontent
{    
    color: white;   
    text-align: center;   
}

.fixedtext 
{
    background: blue; 
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.fillcontent
{
    background: green; 
    position: relative; 
    overflow: auto; 
    z-index: 1; 
    height: 400px;
}
```

A nice to have would also be the use of the "browser-scrollbar" on the right side (not only a short local scrollbar in the green content-box).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You want the rest of the page to scroll with the whole stack of three stuck to the top of the screen?

Comment: The three on the top should be always visible and only the green box should scroll.

Comment: @phil [will this suit](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/LgxJx/1)?

Comment: yeah, this is it! please add it as answer so I could mark the answer as right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `overflow:hidden` to the `html,body,.main` and `overflow:scroll` to the `.main-content`, you can simulate what you need.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="dynamic-content">
        <div class="dynamic-content-text">
            dynamic-content-text<br/>...
        </div>
        <div class="dynamic-content-fixed">dynamic-content-fixed</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        main-content<br />...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
html,body, .main{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header{
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:50px;
    background: red;
}

.dynamic-content{
    padding-top:50px;
}

.dynamic-content-text{
    background:yellow;
}

.dynamic-content-fixed{
    background:blue;
}

.main-content{
    background:green;
    height:100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/LgxJx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with jQuery/ javascript.

First check if the page has a scrollbar, if there is no adjustment is needed. If not, the last container needs to be stretched to fill the rest of the window space.

Add the container heights together and subtract from the window height then set that as height for the last container.

Just have method like (Not tested)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     if(!hasScrollbar()) {
        var filled = $(".errorheader").outerHeight() + ... ;
        $(".fillcontent").height($(window).height()-filled);
     }
 });
```

There are a lot of code for finding if the window has a scrollbar, check here on stackoverflow. If you expect the users to resize the window you could add a callback for $(window).resize();

---

Another possible solution would be to use the body element to fake that the last container expands. If the containers are identified by their background you could just use the same background for  as the last container. Just remember to set the body to fill 100%.